# Non-hyperelliptic families of curves with trivial Ceresa class (or Gross-Schoen class)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-curves, algebraic-cycles, higher-genus-curves

Suppose X/K is a curve over a field K, which we want to think of as non-algebraically closed, and let x be a point of X(K). The *Ceresa cycle* is defined as follows; you can embed X in Jac(X) by sending y to the divisor x-y.  Of course you can also embed X in Jac(X) by sending y to y-x.  This gives you two curves in the abelian variety Jac(X), whose difference is a homologically trivial cycle.  And the cycle class map (combined with the polarization on Jac(X)) gives you a class, called the *Ceresa class*, in

$H^1(G_K, \wedge^3 H (-1) / H)$

where H is the first $\ell$-adic homology of the curve.  (All this is taken from the introduction of Hain-Matsumoto's paper.)  For fans of Shouwu Zhang and his collaborators, this ends up being more or less the same as the Gross-Schoen class whose arithmetic they study very extensively.

The Ceresa class is a really nice invariant of the curve, which, as Hain and Matsumoto explain, is intimately related with the Johnson filtration and the action of $G_K$ on the quotient of $\pi_1(X)$ by the third term of its lower central series.

So one thing we know (it's clear, in fact, from the Ceresa definition) is that the Ceresa class vanishes if X is a hyperelliptic curve.  On the other hand, the Ceresa class is known to be nontrivial for the generic curve of genus g.

**Question:** Can you describe a curve X/K such that

1. X is not hyperelliptic;
2. The monodromy map $G_K \rightarrow \mathbf{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbf{Z}_\ell)$ has open image;
3. The Ceresa class of X is trivial?

Or can we at least prove in some pure thought way that such an X exists?  Or *does* it exist?

I'm more interested in the case where K is something like k(t) than the case where K is a number field, but I'd take either, to start with.

Comment: Could you say more about the cycle class map you are using?  Are you looking at the image of the algebraic cycle in Deligne cohomology, or something like that?

Comment: I just mean etale cohomology -- I suppose this is "really" a motivic question but I don't think I need to invoke anything of that kind to get at what I'm interested in.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say that the Ceresa cycle is homologically trivial, are you saying that the image of the cycle in etale cohomology of $J(X)\otimes_K \overline{K}$ is trivial?  If so, are you asking about the cycle in etale cohomology of $J(X)$?

Comment: I think it is unlikely that such a curve exists  (assuming $K$ is finitely generated and $char(K) = 0$): it is generally believed that the Ceresa cycle is non-torsion modulo algebraic equivalence if $X$ is non-hyperelliptic; this would imply, assuming usual motivic conjectures, that the Ceresa class is also non-trivial

Comment: Wait so I'm completely unaware that it's "generally believed" that non-hyperelliptic curves have non-torsion Ceresa cycle -- who believes this, have they written down why they believe it, etc.?

Comment: My student Lalit Jain pointed out to me the paper "The Griffiths Infinitesimal Invariant for a Curve in its Jacobian," by Collino and Pirola, which shows that a family of genus-g curves whose codimension in M_g is less than ~g/3 has nontrivial Ceresa.  So that's something!

Comment: @ulrich: Quick question -- is there anywhere this "general belief" appears in print?

Comment: @DanielLitt: I don't recall now if I have ever seen the statement in print.

Comment: @ulrich: Just FYI it seems to be false conditional on Beilinson's conjecture, and I now know of some explicit curves (of genus 3 and 7) for which I expect one could actually prove it's false...

Comment: @DanielLitt: I did see your paper on arXiv, the abstract looked very interesting but I have not yet read the paper.